# Rails: "Waiting" HTML screen while PDF is being generated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack, prawn

I have a Rails app that can generate PDFs using Prawn.  Some of them can be fairly large (tens or hundreds of pages) and take some noticeable time to generate.  What I would like to do is display some HTML page with a message like "Please wait while we create your document (spinning icon)", and then display the PDF once it is done.

I was thinking of using Rack Middleware to do this.  Admittedly, I know nothing about Rack except having watched [Railscasts Episode #151](http://railscasts.com/episodes/151-rack-middleware).  It seems like I could intercept the request to these large PDFs, display the HTML waiting page, then intercept the response and replace the HTML with the generated PDF content.

Is this possible?  Will this work with Rack?  If not, what is something that might accomplish this?  If it will work with Rack, can someone give me a generic explanation of the steps to do this?  I've been searching the internet, and the Rack stuff I've found isn't very beginner-friendly (thus, I'm asking here).

Any help will be much appreciated.

- Ian

Comment: Why can't you use a regular Rails controller that either renders the "Please wait" view, or redirects to the file download URL? If a user for some reason access the download directly before the file is done, it's his own fault.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that this is what you want, but you can send message to the browser via something like [private_pub](https://github.com/ryanb/private_pub/) after PDF is ready and handle receiving of that message on the client side (show a link, start download etc).